# Cloud9 C9.io how can I Run cakephp 3.0

Tags: cakephp, github, cloud

I have successfully uploaded my cakephp project in workspace of cloud9 I am able to run demo php/index.php it is working well but when I am accessing cakephp I am getting this error 
You must enable the intl extension to use CakePHP. in /home/ubuntu/workspace/hw/config/bootstrap.php on line 38

What is this and how can I edit php.ini file in cloud9 There is nothing mentioned in cloud docs

Comment: How about starting with the [**documentation**](https://docs.c9.io/v1.0/docs), have you ever had a look at it?

Comment: yes I had checked it but there is no solution for my problem I want to edit php.ini

Comment: **https://docs.c9.io/v1.0/docs/writing-a-php-app#modifying-php-ini** | **https://docs.c9.io/v1.0/docs/symfony2**

Comment: Ya I check the file and there is no php.ini in workspace it is inside their root not accessible

Comment: Then you haven't [**set up the workspace**](https://docs.c9.io/v1.0/docs/creating-new-workspace#hosted-workspaces) properly, out of the box a hosted PHP workspace has a `php.ini` file in the workspace root. However there's no need to edit this file at all, just install the extension as mentioned in the linked docs, (re)start your app/server, and that's it.